# ReactiveUI BindTo not updating the ReactiveList

Tags: c#, binding, observablecollection, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have a `ReactiveObject` class named `GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter`:

```
public class GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter : ReactiveObject
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }

    int selectionCode;
    public int SelectionCode
    {
        get { return selectionCode; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref selectionCode, value); }
    }

    public ReactiveList<IssueTypeSearchFilter> IssueTypeFilterList { get; set; }

    public GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter(int catID, string catTitle, List<IssueTypeSearchFilter> issueTypeList)
    {
        this.CategoryID = catID;
        this.CategoryTitle = catTitle;
        this.IssueTypeFilterList = new ReactiveList<IssueTypeSearchFilter>(issueTypeList);
    }
}
```

Then in `IssueTypeFilterTableViewDelegate` class, one of its properties is `GroupedIssueTypesFilter`:

```
public ReactiveList<GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter> GroupedIssueTypesFilter { get; set; }
```

I also have a `ViewController` and its `ViewModel`. I used `BindTo` to bind one of the view model properties to that class:

```
IssueTypeFilterTableViewDelegate tvd = new IssueTypeFilterTableViewDelegate();
this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.ViewModel.GroupedStandardIssueTypesTV)
    .BindTo(this, x => x.tvd.GroupedIssueTypesFilter);
```

`GroupedStandardIssueTypesTV` type is `ReactiveList<GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter>`.

Later, with some operation inside the `ViewModel`, the `GroupedStandardIssueTypesTV.IssueTypeFilterList` value is **changed**.

But, `GroupedIssueTypesFilter.IssueTypeFilterList` value is **not changed**. I need to close the View, re-open it, then its value will be updated.

How to make the `GroupedIssueTypesFilter` follows the changes in `GroupedStandardIssueTypesTV`?

Answer (score 3):

Fully agree with [@ramonesteban78 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41012423/1362539).

But you can go in another way and refill your ReactiveList with Clear and Add/AddRange methods.

Like this:

```
public GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter(int catID, string catTitle, List<IssueTypeSearchFilter> issueTypeList)
{
    this.CategoryID = catID;
    this.CategoryTitle = catTitle;
    this.IssueTypeFilterList.Clear();
    this.IssueTypeFilterList.AddRange(issueTypeList);
}
```

Don't forget read about 'Suppressing Notifications' here: https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/lists/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not raising changes in your ReactiveList declaring it like:

```
public ReactiveList<IssueTypeSearchFilter> IssueTypeFilterList { get; set; }
```

Try this:

```
ReactiveList<IssueTypeSearchFilter> issueTypeFilterList
public ReactiveList<IssueTypeSearchFilter> IssueTypeFilterList 
{ 
    get { return  issueTypeFilterList; }; 
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref issueTypeFilterList, value); }; 
}
```

Without the `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` you won`t be communicating changes to the view in your collection.

You can also subscribe to the observables that ReactiveList exposes like:

```
ItemsAdded
ItemsRemoved
ItemsMoved
Changed
etc
```

More info here: https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/lists/index.html

Comment: I already try this before and it's not working. Every time I reload the table, the list is not updating.